# How to change Text and font color in Pull To refresh Android

Tags: android, android-listview

How to change the (Release to Refresh) in Pull to refresh library I am using the follwoing library [chrisbanes / Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) and here is the result of my work [My App](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ng9cgx1x1rpsl2/Screenshot_2014-02-23-11-26-38.png)

here is my xml file:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

here is my logic:

```
PullToRefreshListView pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview); 

pullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
 @Override
    public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
        new LoadNews().execute();
    }
});

    private class LoadNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if(database.countRows() > 0)
            dataList = database.retrieveAll();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        lv.onRefreshComplete();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(dataList != null)
            UpdateList();
    }
}
```

**How Could I change the literal text and the text color ?**

Comment: Nope. Not what we do. Try them and figure it out yourself. Please post back here with code and specific, detailed explanations of any problems that you may encounter.

Comment: @MattClark I have edited my question please look at it

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this without an answer. So posting it now.

Here, the strings passed are from strings.xml and the methods are pretty self-explanatory. Cheers to Chris Banes :)

```
pullToRefreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setPullLabel(
                getString(R.string.product_pull_label));

pullToRefreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setRefreshingLabel(
                getString(R.string.product_refresh_label));


pullToRefreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setReleaseLabel(
                getString(R.string.product_release_label));
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ptr:ptrHeaderTextColor="@color/text_corner"
    />
```